# How can I store an array into dynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following struct:

```
type User struct {
  ID       string    `json:"id"`
  Name     string    `json:"name"`
  LastName string    `json:"lastName"`
  User     string    `json:"user"`
  Password string    `json:"password"`
  Vehicles []Vehicle `json:"vehicles"`
}
type Vehicle struct {
  Plate string `json:"plate"`
}
```

I want to store an array of Vehicles in my DynamoDB. I did some research and I found that I should use the following code:

```
input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
    TableName: aws.String(tableUsers),
    Item: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        "id": {
            S: aws.String(fmt.Sprintf("%v", uuid)),
        },
        "name": {
            S: aws.String(user.Name),
        },
        "lastName": {
            S: aws.String(user.LastName),
        },
        "user": {
            S: aws.String(user.User),
        },
        "password": {
            S: aws.String(user.Password),
        },
        "vehicles": {
            L: [{
                M: {
                    "plate": {S: aws.String("test")},
                },
            }],
        },
    },
}
```

But I keep having a syntax error in:

```
L: [{
    M: {
        "plate": {S: aws.String("test")},
    },
}],
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the dynamodb's godoc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/#AttributeValue

You can see that the field `L` has the following type: []*AttributeValue

When you create a slice litteral you should specify its type. 
So for you case it's:

```
L: []*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
  {
    M: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
      "plate": {S: aws.String("test")}
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to better understand struct, slices and map your can read the following articles:

- https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals
- https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action