# Terraform aws dynamodb item - preparation of data

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to load data into a dynamodb table from input variables.  I'm using locals to manipulate the input data into the correct shape for loading into my table.  What seems like a simple thing has

My Variable definition:

```
variable "templates" {
    description = "List of templates available to be used by notifications."
    type = list(object({
        description = string
        html_part = string
        text_part = string
        template_id = string
        subject = string
        substitutions = list(object({
            name = string
            default = string
            required = bool
        }))
    }))
    default = []
}
```

Initialising that variable:

```
  templates = [{
    template_id   = "TestNotification1"
    subject       = "This is a test"
    description   = "Test notification 1"
    html_part     = <<EOT
<html>
  <body>
{{test}} This {{test1}} is {{test2}} the HTML Part
  </body>
</html>
EOT
    text_part     = "This is a test"
    substitutions = [{
      default = "test"
      required = true
      name = "test1"
    }
    ]
  }]
```

My attempt to convert the variables into a dynamodb item entry. This is where my problem is.

```
locals {
  templates = tomap([for template in var.templates : 

{
  "TemplateId": { "S": "${template.template_id}"},
  "Type": { "S": "STANDARD"},
  "TemplateDescription": { "S": "${template.description}"},
  "Subject": { "S": "${template.subject}"},
  "HtmlPart": { "S": "${replace(template.html_part,"\n","")}"},
  "TextPart": { "S": "${template.text_part}"},
  "Substitutions":[for substitution in template.substitutions : {
    "Name" : { "S": "${substitution.name}"},
    "Required" : { "S": "${substitution.required}"},
    "DefaultValue" : { "S": "${substitution.default}"}
  }
]
}

  ])
}
```

This produces the following error:

```
Invalid value for "v" parameter: cannot convert tuple to map of any single type.
```

Loading into dynamodb table (obviously not getting that far):

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "templates" {
  table_name = aws_dynamodb_table.default_template_table.name
  hash_key   = "TemplateId"
  for_each = local.templates
  item = each.value
}
```

If I didn't have to do the substitions I could have something like this which works, but I can't figure out how to include my substitutions in this?:

```
locals {
  templates = toset([for template in var.templates : 
<<ITEM
{
  "TemplateId": { "S": "${template.template_id}"},
  "Type": { "S": "STANDARD"},
  "TemplateDescription": { "S": "${template.description}"},
  "Subject": { "S": "${template.subject}"},
  "HtmlPart": { "S": "${replace(template.html_part,"\n","")}"},
  "TextPart": { "S": "${template.text_part}"}
}
ITEM
  ])
}
```

Comment: `"v" parameter"` - what is `v`? I don't see any such parameter in your code.

Comment: @Marcin it's a terraform thing.  I don't really know but it's not referring to a character in my code.

Comment: Anyway.  I think my attempt that produces this error is just broken from the start.  I posted in the last snippet to see if anyone has some idea on how i can perhaps include my substitutions array in there.  Is there some way i can smack a for loop in the middle of a multi line string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this.  The solution is to jsonencode the whole json object and use the dynamodb L and M Attribute Type for my list of substituion objects.

Note the **cannot unmarshall array** error appeared to be related to not using the correct Attribute type for an array when inserting into DDB.  I found this post useful: [How can I store an array into dynamoDB table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60580541/how-can-i-store-an-array-into-dynamodb-table)

```
locals {
  templates = toset([for template in var.templates : 
  jsonencode({
  "TemplateId": { "S": "${template.template_id}"},
  "Type": { "S": "STANDARD"},
  "TemplateDescription": { "S": "${template.description}"},
  "Subject": { "S": "${template.subject}"},
  "HtmlPart": { "S": "${replace(template.html_part,"\n","")}"},
  "TextPart": { "S": "${template.text_part}"},
  "Substitutions":{"L": [for substitution in template.substitutions : {
    "M" : {
      "Name" : { "S": "${substitution.name}"},
      "DefaultValue" : { "S": "${substitution.default}"}
    }
   }] }

})
  
  ])
}
```

Comment: ends with } missing

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Substitutions` to your second form using `jsonencode`:

```
    templates = toset([for template in var.templates : 
<<ITEM
{
  "TemplateId": { "S": "${template.template_id}"},
  "Type": { "S": "STANDARD"},
  "TemplateDescription": { "S": "${template.description}"},
  "Subject": { "S": "${template.subject}"},
  "HtmlPart": { "S": "${replace(template.html_part,"\n","")}"},
  "TextPart": { "S": "${template.text_part}"},
  "Substitutions":${jsonencode([for substitution in template.substitutions : {
      "Name" : { "S": "${substitution.name}"},
      "Required" : { "S": "${substitution.required}"},
      "DefaultValue" : { "S": "${substitution.default}"}
   }])}
}
ITEM
  ])
```

But this is unlikely to work anyway, as TF can't process such a complex data structure and you will end up with `cannot unmarshal array` error. The issue has been already reported in TF several times, e.g. [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12256).

Thus you have to simplify your `templates` items to be regular flat maps, not nested, or use `local-exec` to populate your dynamodb table.

Comment: What about `jsonencode` on the accessed values from the iterated `map`? I may be missing something here.